# How I can properly auto-mount a drive using fstab?

Tags: raspberry-pi, fstab, automount

On a raspberry pi, I can mount an external USB HDD via both `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/sda1` and `sudo mount -a`.

However, I can't seem to achieve the same effect inside fstab and a reboot. That file looks like

```
/dev/sda1       /media/sda1     vfat    uid=1000,gid=1000
```

**How do I correctly translate the working commands above into fstab and have this drive automatically mounted at reboot?**

## Errata/Misc

**The USB drive** is seen via

```
root@raspberrypi:/dev/disk/by-id# ls -al | grep usb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jan 11 19:38 usb-WDC_WD25_...XXXXXXXXXXXX-0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jan 11 19:38 usb-WDC_WD25_...XXXXXXXXX-0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
```

Comment: as long as `sudo mount -a` works, I'd say the configuration is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Pi, but on all the Linux distro's I use FSTAB requires 6 fields - the last 2 being a pair of numbers (and which appear to be missing from your config)

The 5th field can be 0 and, according to the man pages the 6th field should  be 2 - the 5th field is used by the dump command to determine if the filesystem needs to be dumped, while the 6th field is is the order in which filesystems are checked.

So try

> /dev/sda1       /media/sda1     vfat    uid=1000,gid=1000 0 2

Answer (score 1):

This is directly from my fstab file:

```
/dev/sda1  /mnt/usb1  vfat  auto,exec,sync,rw,flush,suid,umask=0022,nouser,uid=pi,gid=pi  0  0
```

Note that the directory /mnt/usb1 must exist and have correct premissions. I am running Jessie on my Pi.